# jquery fullpage.js - onload on touch devices

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I'm using this fabulous plugin, but I stumbled upon an error on touch devices.
I'm calling a callback function fired thanks to "afterLoad", but on mobile devices nothing appends (on desktop / laptop all is ok).

Here's the code:

```
$('#my_class').fullpage({
  sectionSelector: '.my_section',
  css3: true,
  resize: false,
  controlArrows: false,
  slidesNavigation: true,
  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
    alert('test'),
  }
});
```

Please, could someone help me?

Thanks :)

Comment: Is there any information in the JavaScript logs or console? Have you considered trying this with `resize` set to `true`? Can we see the HTML produced on the mobile device?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response; here's a demo link. I check the console, but there isn't any error. http://goo.gl/jVnG9q Thanks :)

Comment: Demo link not working, JavaScript error (imageLoaded is not a function)

Comment: Thans, fixed the imagesloaded issue :)

Comment: Look into jquery.shortcodes.frontend.js, there you use Modernizr.touch to initialize fullpage with 3 parameters - and no afterLoad function ( that method is only set for non-touch devices) - your code behaves exactly like it should, that is not a bug, it's a feature.